# Android Display a random Item from List without showing the ListView

Tags: android-listview

I am practicing on this project called GetTours i got from github, now
I want to display random Item from the `ListView` without seeing the `ListView`. not only show random item from `ListView`, but also print the details of the items, the item contains Name, address and lat long value for the map marker. 
is that even possible?

or maybe, Teach me how to create a list that contains a name, address and lat long value and how to display it. I am also planning of randomizing it every time i shake the device. I had an app that do shake an random with a single data array, now I want to randomize a place with Name, address and a Map marker in the said location per shake. please help!

Comment: If you want the code i can give it. just help me, please!

Comment: What have you tried? and don't post a comment to your own question, edit your question instead. And yes, it's possible.

Comment: oh sorry i'm such a newbie here, and newbie programmer too. I have tried Collections but it gives me an error. please help

Comment: which listview adapter does the app use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListView is not needed here, save your items in a List :

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>;
items.add(item1);
items.add(item2);
//...
```

Then select a random number with the maximum as the length of your list :

```
final int random = Random.nextInt(items.size());
```

And then, do what you need to do with the data :

```
Item randomItem = items.get(random);
nameTextView.setText(randomItem.getName());
priceTextView.setText("" + randomItem.getPrice());
//...
```

Comment: can i add a latitude and longitude value for the location map? how?? sorry i forgot to include the lat long value for the map marker too. sorry

Comment: If you already have the latitude and longitude value, you just need to add them to the Item (or any name you want) object like `public class Item { private String mName; private double mPrice; private long mLatitude; private long mLongitude; public setName(String name) { mName = name; } public String getName(){ return mName; } // and the same for each variable` then you will be able to get them from the object and do your stuff with it.

Comment: Where does nameTextView and priceTextView come from dude? it gives me an error.

Comment: I put that as an example, you don't have to use them, it depends on how you want to do with your data. If you want to use the textview, you can follow this example to instanciate them: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/android/textview.html